# Google Cloud Function restrict developer/editor access to function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I have several google cloud functions for a google cloud project. We have multiple project editors who currently have the ability to create, edit, delete cloud functions within the project as they see fit. I would like to be able to create a google cloud function that only I have access to within the project. Is this possible? I've looked at custom IAM policies but I can't tell if its possible using them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions doesn't support per-account IAM for the purpose of managing the functions in a project.  An account either has some level of access to **all** the functions in the entire project (as listed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles)), or none at all.

There is [per-account controls for **invoking** functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam), as described in the documentation, but that is not the same as the permissions for managing the functions.

If you really need to isolate accounts per function for management, I believe your only option is to deploy the functions to different projects.  That will certainly make other things difficult, but possibly doable.

**Update:** Currently Cloud Functions support granting roles to users on an entire project or on individual functions

This can be configured with the following command:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
  --member=MEMBER_TYPE \
  --role=ROLE
```